# Packages dplyr and choroplethr are incompatible

Tags: r, dplyr, choroplethr

Running the folloing code works

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
 group_by(cyl) %>% 
 summarise (mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

# A tibble: 3 x 2

```
 cyl mean_mpg
<dbl>    <dbl>
1     4 26.66364
2     6 19.74286
3     8 15.10000
```

after loading choroplethr it does not work, even if we load dplyr again

```
library(choroplethr)

mtcars %>% 
 group_by(cyl) %>% 
 summarise (mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

mean_mpg
1 20.09062
```

looks like the two packages are incompatible. I used them before without problems, but after upgrading to a new version of R, RStudio and the two packages, they no longr work together.

Answer (score 2):

When you load `choroplethr`, it loads `plyr`, as well. And as it has been mentioned time and again, don't load `plyr` after loading `dplyr`.

In your case, load `choroplethr` first and then `dplyr`, and everything should work fine.

```
library(choroplethr)
Loading required package: acs
Loading required package: stringr
Loading required package: plyr
Loading required package: XML

Attaching package: ‘acs’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    apply
```

Though `choroplethr` only depends on `acs`, `acs` depends on `plyr`; hence when you check the `choroplethr` CRAN page, it might not be obvious that it also loads `plyr`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I loaded it in the other order (dplyr then choroplethr) before without any problems, but now the load sequence has to be reversed.

Comment: Yes, this "feature" of choroplethr was introduced in version 3.5.2: http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2016/04/04/new-version-choroplethr/. The only good thing I can say about it is that it fixes even worse problems that no on seems to be able to adequately explain. I really hate that choroplethr now depends on acs. But at least at the time, there seemed no other fix to the problems I outline in the blog post.